# How to add plotline in highchart to the x-axis by passing a value and check if the value exist in a string or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, react-highcharts

I am working on a high chart column and a line graph, I am not able to add a plotline to the x-axis by passing a value which is a number and the x-axis value is a list of string

In this issue, the number is provided by the user and the value of the x-axis is array array coming from the JSON data

the array that I have is given below -

```js
const xAxisValues =   ['0.00-0.15', '0.16-0.30', '0.31-0.45', '0.46-0.60', '0.61-0.75', '0.76-0.90', '0.91-1.05']
```

and lets the number given by the user is

```js
const plotValue = 0.2
```

So what I want here is we want to get the closest value from the xAxisValues from the plot value, so the result will be "0.15-0.30" as 0.2 exist between this value

Another Example -

```
const xAxisValue = ['0.00-0.05', '0.06-0.10', '0.11-0.15', '0.15-0.20', '0.21-0.25', '0.26-0.30', '0.31-0.35', '0.36-0.40', '0.41-0.45', '0.46-0.50', '0.51-0.55', '0.56-0.60', '0.61-0.65', '0.66-0.70', '0.71-0.75', '0.76-0.80', '0.81-0.85', '0.86-0.90', '0.91-0.95', '0.96-1.00']

const plotValue = 0.3

const plotLineLocation = "0.30-0.35"

const plotValue = 0.47

const plotLineLocation = "0.46-0.50"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `load` event, to do all neccessery operations.

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

I started from parsing data array to get raw numbers.

```
    let xAxisValuesParsed = [];

    xAxisValues.forEach(value => {
      xAxisValuesParsed.push(value.split("-"))
    });
```

Then I did some calculations to get the closest number:

```
    let closestNumbers = [];

    xAxisValuesParsed.forEach((value, i) => {
      closestNumbers.push(value.reduce((a, b) => {
        return Math.abs(b - plotValue) < Math.abs(a - plotValue) ? b : a;
      }));
    })

    let closest = closestNumbers.reduce((a, b) => {
      return Math.abs(b - plotValue) < Math.abs(a - plotValue) ? b : a;
    });
```

Having closest number, I'm able to find `plotLineLocation` in `xAxisValuesParsed` array:

```
    let plotLineLocation = xAxisValuesParsed.find(({
      0: n,
      1: m,
    }, i) => {
      if (n === closest) {
        return n === closest
      } else if (m === closest) {
        return m === closest
      }
    })
```

It will be difficult to add a `plotLine` in the relevant place based on the `category` type `xAxis`. I added another axis to simulate intervals as in the strings.

**Check the demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5vgbxmj3/

I'm not sure what exactly your example should looks like, so feel free to ask any further questions!